# Location header returned by HTTPFound does not include non-standard port number

Tags: python, redirect, nginx, pyramid, gunicorn

I have a Pyramid application running on gunicorn (listening on Unix socket) behind nginx (listening on port 8080). When Pyramid view returns `HTTPFound(location='/')` HTTP response contains `Location: http://example.host/` without port number, so users get "could not connect" errors. I can't figure out where to specify the non-standard port number, or (preferably) how to tell Pyramid to extract it from the request when generating `Location` header.

Excerpt from the application config:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
host = unix:%(here)s/run/server.sock
workers = 4
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    root /path/to/app;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/app/run/server.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }
    location /static {
        root /path/to/app/static;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the server port, use [`host_port`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.host_port)

Also according to [`rfc2616`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30), you should really be sending an absolute URI not a relative one in the `Location` header.

Comment: Thanks, your response has pushed me in the right direction:
1) I replaced hard-coded strings in `location` parameters with `request.route_url` calls (my bad, `'/'` was so much easier to type than `request.route_url('frontpage')`).
2) Nginx proxy_params contained
`proxy_set_header Host $host;`
but it should be
`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`

Comment: @Burhan: Pyramid takes care of generating absolute URLs for the application developer so that's not something to worry about here; what was missing was the proper route call and ngnix configuration.